# finding a key for DES

Tags: java, cryptography, encryption, des

working on a problem of encrypyting and decrypting using the DES given in java.
Ive already figured out how to encrypt and decrypt pretty easy but now im stuck.
For the current problem i am having I have the plaintext and the coorisponding cipher text (which is in the format of 8 hex pairs ex: A5 33 1F ..) but i also have the first 4 hexidecimal bits of the key. Im not really asking for code but more of an idea how i would go about tackling this problem! anything will help! this is my decryption code (just included it to show i am workin hard :) ). thanks guys!

```
public static void decrypt(){
    Cipher cipher;
    SecretKeySpec key;
    byte [] keyBytes;
    byte [] pt;
    byte [] ct;
    String plaintxt;

    keyBytes = new byte [] {(byte)0xFE, (byte)0xDC, (byte)0xBA, (byte)0x98, (byte)0x76, (byte)0x54, (byte)0x32, (byte)0x10};
    key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DES");
    ct = new byte [] {(byte) 0x2C, (byte) 0xE6, (byte) 0xDD, (byte) 0xA4, (byte) 0x98, (byte) 0xCA, (byte) 0xBA, (byte) 0xB9};

    try{
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        pt = cipher.doFinal(ct);
        printByteArray(pt);
        plaintxt = byteToHex(pt);
        hexToAscii(plaintxt);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you asking "how do I determine the key, given plaintext and ciphertext?".  If so, that's a very hard problem.

Comment: well yeah, but i also have the first 4 bytes already so i only need to solve for 4 bytes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brute force.

Enumerate over every key that it could be (given the fixed bytes) until you get a decryption that makes the plaintext and ciphertext match. It'll take edit: 2^37 attempts on average, though, so don't expect it to happen fast :)

There are some properties of DES that let you crack it faster, but they're very difficult to implement and I doubt you'd be expected to learn them. But if you are interested, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard#Security_and_cryptanalysis

Comment: Yeah haha thats the one thing i know for sure that it will take a while. someone else in my class said that it took like 30 min to find the solution! Thats carzy but awesome! So are you saying just like iterate through each possibility, kinda like say my first 4 bits which i have are for example " 12 A3 5B FF " and start the next four bits @ zeros and then slowly increment my way up while the whole time checking if it equals my cipher text? :D

Comment: Yeah, pretty much. The only reason why this is a feasible attack on DES is because its key size is so small - 54 bits. AES has a key size of 128, 192 or 256 bits - and that doesn't mean it's about 2-4 times as hard, it means it's *2 harder for EVERY EXTRA BIT IN THE KEY. So 2^64 times harder or more :)

Comment: Yeah pretty cool stuff. were learning ll about that in my cryptography class! thanks for the help man im gonna try to implement the brute force attack now!

Comment: Well one quick question. if the key im using is a byte array, how would i increment? Put values in the last four spots in the array like use a couple for loops? like 4 for loops? im jut not sure how i would change the numbers, i clearly understand the concept.

Comment: Have an index set to 0. Increment the lowest byte by 1 - if it overflows to 0, then increment the index and increment the next byte too. As soon as you don't get an overflow to 0 set the index back to 0. Something like that